# Update multiple fields' value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm newbie for manipulating MongoDB recently, but I really need to update some fields like these..

```
db_name: test   
table_name: info

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54bf9ab4f8eda6747567b122"),
    "archives" : [
        {
            "evalution" : {
                "positive" : 0,
                "undefine" : 0,
                "negative" : 0
            },
            "source" : ObjectId("54cb6f455decd8037528756b")
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to **increase** `positive` and `undefine` by `1`, and if `evalution` **doesn't exists**,

```
"evalution" : {
    "positive" : 0,
    "undefine" : 0,
    "negative" : 0
}
```

should be added to the object.

I don't know if I express myself clearly, but I really need some help..

Comment: Do you want to update all the elements in the `archives` array?

Comment: @BatScream      I just want to update `positive` and `undefine` in `evalution`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But archives array may have multiple elements, each element may have a `evaluation` attribute. So you want to update `positive` and `undefine` of all the elements?

Comment: @BatScream so sorry, I didn't explain clearly, I just want to update this one only --> `"_id" : ObjectId("54bf9ab4f8eda6747567b122")`

Comment: is the source filed exists for each sub document?

Comment: @achuth    yes, `source` is exists for each sub document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If evalution doesn't exists u can create a sub-doc using following query.

```
db.test.update(
 {_id:ObjectId("54bf9ab4f8eda6747567b122"),
 "archives.source" : ObjectId("54cb6f455decd8037528756b"),
 "archives.evalution":{$exists:false}},
 {$set:{"archives.$.evalution":{positive:1,negative:0,undefine:1}}}
)
```

**NOTE**: Positional operator is only upto one level, so u cannot increment the values until you know the index of archieves array.

you get the the index of the archieves array and increment using following command. In this case **0** where 
    source = ObjectId("54cb6f455decd8037528756b")

```
db.test.update(
 {_id:_id:ObjectId("54bf9ab4f8eda6747567b122")},
 {$inc:{"archives.0.evalution.positive":1}}
)
```

Comment: Maybe I can't really understand your meaning,  may be what the wrong way I did seemed not to be succeed  --> `db.test.update({'_id':ObjectId('54bf9ab4f8eda3857567b122')}, {$set:{'archives.$.evalution':{'positive':1}}})`

Comment: but I want to `$inc` `positive` and `undefine` instead of use `$set`, so sorry I can't really understand your meaning ..

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know what the semantics of the update are. Why are you incrementing those two fields? Why are you incrementing two fields, as if doing a count, but if the fields don't exist you want to set default values to `0` (as opposed to, say, `1`)? Is there a semantic difference between "`evaluation` doesn't exist" and the value

```
{
    "positive" : 0,
    "undefine" : 0,
    "negative" : 0
}
```

for `evaluation`? Or between "`evaluation` doesn't exist" and

```
{
    "positive" : -1,
    "undefine" : -1,
    "negative" : 0
}
```

for the value? It seems like no, for at least one of those default values, and so you should set `evaluation` to have the appropriate default value on insert of the document or of the array element. If you do that, your update is simple:

```
db.info.update(
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("54bf9ab4f8eda6747567b122"), 
        "archives.source" : ObjectId("54cb6f455decd8037528756b")
    },
    {
        "$inc" : { 
            "archives.$.evalution.positive" : 1,
            "archives.$.evalution.undefine" : 1,
        }
    }
)
```

Also, you have some typos, I think:

1. `evalution` probably means `evaluation` or possibly `evolution`?
2. the proper complement to `positive` and `negative` is `undefined`